# FFMPEG overlay transparent background

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg

I am new to integrating ffmpeg to android and i am able to achieve creating video from static images but the problem is the overlay of 2nd video is showing black background. credit:[**FfmpegController**]
https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg-java/blob/master/src/org/ffmpeg/android/FfmpegController.java

This is the code

```
ffmpeg -y, -i, mov.mp4, -filter_complex, [1]scale=iw+200:ih+200 [pip]; [0][pip] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-100:main_h-overlay_h-200, -i, ffmpeg , -vf, zoompan=d=25+'50*eq(in,3)'+'100*eq(in,5)', -strict, -2, -vcodec, mpeg4, -t, 6, -c:v, libx264, -pix_fmt, yuv420p,mov2.mp4
```

need transparent background so that the 1st video is visible clearly...Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see in your code the second video, I means there is only one input, mov.mp4

Comment: friend at the end of the code you can see mov2.mp4

Comment: Hum I thought it was the resultant video. Ok, I'im not in android, but I tried this command and its works.
ffmpeg -i outputt.mp4 -i jump.mp4 -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=iw+2
00:ih+200[pip];[0:v][pip]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-100:main_h-overlay_h-100[overl
aid];[overlaid]zoompan=d=25+'50*eq(in,3)'+'100*eq(in,5)'" -acodec aac -strict -2
 -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p result.mp4

So, in your command, if mov2.mp4 is the second input file, where is the output file name? I suppose that mov2.mp4 is the file you want to overlay to mov.mp4 are you sure that his background is transparent?

Comment: What's with the commas and misplaced options? You should show the actual, unscripted command and the complete console output/log.

Comment: @Ediruth : thx for your precious time, no background of top[front] overlay window is black in color,i want it to be transparent. bcoz i am displaying slideshow from many images and its always showing black color.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard : thx for your precious time,as i am using FfmpegController.java class so i am overwriting ffmpeg lib by passing the commands through arraylist in android so the commas .it works fine but the o/p i am getting is black background for top overlay ,just want to make transparent...

Comment: @Deepak one question.  The video you want to overlay, it is you who made it with ffmpeg? If it is, I suppose that you made it from many (transparents) images, and in this case I hope you use a good codec which support transparency (png does, libx264 doesn't); because if the resultant video is not transparent, you cannot hope that when you will overlay it, it will be transparent.

Comment: @Ediruth : you are absolutely right friend. I got your point. will try it with another codec and see the o/p..

Comment: @Ediruth : I am using libx264,which alternative is best which supports transparency ..Thanks in advance

Comment: If you absolutely want your overlaid video file to be a MP4, encode it with png and choose the pixel format yuva420p (it will give -vcodec png -pix_fmt yuva420p).